# C++ Std queue and vector performance

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, std, deque

I've been working with graphs lately, and I am looking into returning a path from a graph. The path needs to be returned as a std vector containing all of the nodes with the starting node first.

I've been looking at two options:
- use the slow vector insert method to add the nodes at the front of the vector
- use a deque to add the nodes to the front (push_front), which is much faster. Then copying the deque to the vector using std::copy

Is there a significant performance boost using one method over the other?

Comment: Why not push to the back of the vector instead?

Comment: I suggest using a linked-list if you dont need direct access to elements

Comment: I think you should focus on the main Algorithms that you can find your path, other than not so important data structure you choose,  because both are O(n) for vector and dequeue.  In addition, do you think std::copy consumes no time and space?

Comment: @Kilanny That is hard to recommend without knowing the exact usage patterns. Lists have slower iteration times than contiguous storage data types such as `vector` due to poor cache locality.

Comment: You say `queue` in the title and `deque` in the body. Which one is it? Both are things in the standard library.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're returning a path, you presumably have an upper bound on its length. Therefore, you can call create a `vector`, call [`reserve`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/) and later (as @user2079303 writes) call [`push_back`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/) to add vertices to the path.

```
const auto n = <graph_size>
std::vector<size_t> path;
path.reserve(n)
...
v.push_back(i); // Push whatever you want.
```

Now the problem is that, at least from the question, it seems like `v` is in the reversed order. However, you can simply call [`std::reverse`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse):

```
std::reverse(std::begin(v), std::end(v));
```

So, using only a `vector`:

- You're allocating a single data structure instead of two; moreover, using `reserve` there will be a single memory allocation.
- The use of `reverse` at the end simply replaces the use of `copy` you would have to do from the deque to the vector.

Comment: You don't need to `std::reverse()` if you remember to iterate over the return value the other way around, using `vector.rbegin()` and `vector.rend()`. If I know that a container is organized 'the wrong way round' I find the reverse iterators come in quite handy!

Comment: @haavee Good point - you might as well reverse "the convention", if it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking at wrapping a `std::vector` in a `std::queue` then the `std::queue` will push elements to the *back* of the vector (the fast way).

Even if not however, because a `std::vector` is contiguous storage, it is possible it will out-perform a `std::deque` even if you `push_font()` because it plays well with the `CPU` cache where shuffling data is fast.

But why not try both and profile the code to see which one performs better?